# Cant find the issue here, help please

Tags: java

Multiple markers at this line   - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement    - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable    - Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete       Assignment     - Syntax error on token "else", invalid (

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NGG {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int x1, x2;
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("\n  Guess X from 10 - 0: ");
        x1 = scan.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("");
        x2 = ((int)(Math.random()*10));
        System.out.println(x2);
        
        if (x2 == x1) {
        System.out.println("Victory");
        } else if(x2 > x1 && x2 < x1) {
        System.out.println("Lose");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow, can you mark by a comment the line where the error happened ?

Comment: The code in your question compiles for me (javac 1.8.0_292).

Comment: Code compiles fine. Logic is incorrect, but compiles fine.

Comment: Hello,

Code compiles fine for me, Did you make sure the file is saved correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes to it.

nice game :)

```
public class NGG {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NGG ngg = new NGG();
        ngg.game();
    }

   private void game(){
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

       int enteredNumber, guessedNumber;
       System.out.println("\n  Guess number between 0 - 10: ");
       enteredNumber = scan.nextInt();

       guessedNumber = ((int)(Math.random()*10));
       System.out.println(guessedNumber);

       if (guessedNumber == enteredNumber) {
           System.out.println("Victory");
       } else {
           System.out.println("Lost: number was " + guessedNumber);
       }
    }

}
```

did some minor refactoring and updated the logic to check if the guessed number/random number is same as the entered number then you get "victory" otherwise you Lose and shows you what the guessed/random number was.

Comment: Hi @dilbert2219, it would be helpful if you also explain the changes to the OP.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hey @Legend7454_, I did some minor refactoring and updated the logic to check if the guessed number/random number is same as the entered number then you get "victory" otherwise you Lose and shows you what the guessed/random number was.